# Arranging bytes from a packet

Tags: arrays, byte

I made a small program to read my mac address but i cant get the read out to look right.
right now my output looks like 302545261200
but i would like it to look like 00:12:26:45:25:30

here's the snipet of code im using

case "MAC":

```
                cmd = HexToByte(StrObytes);
                ser.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
                read_MAC = new byte[500];
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                ser.Read(read_MAC, 0, ser.BytesToRead);
                mac_bytes = new byte[6];
                int u = 0;
                for (int i = 8; i >= 3; i--)
                {
                    mac_bytes[u] = read_MAC[i];
                    u++;
                }

                textBox1.Text = ByteArrayToString(mac_bytes);
                break;
```

Comment: Well, your loop is reversing them, so don't be surprised that the bytes come out in that order.

Comment: thank you for your reply, if i make it cmd = HexToByte(StrObytes);
                ser.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
                read_MAC = new byte[500];
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                ser.Read(read_MAC, 0, ser.BytesToRead);  the output is 2646120012264525300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F4717E   . im new to programming and my eyes are not open yet.

Comment: got it but i wonder if there is a more simple way. `for (int i = 3; i <= 8; i++)
                {
                    mac_bytes[u] = read_MAC[i];
                    u++;
                }
                string macAddStr = ByteArrayToString(mac_bytes);
                string macAddStrNew = macAddStr;
                int insertedCount = 0;
                for(int i = 2; i < macAddStr.Length; i=i+2)  
                macAddStrNew = macAddStrNew.Insert(i+insertedCount++, ":");
                textBox1.Text = macAddStrNew;`